# Number of entries in DB PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count

I am creating a function to show how many users are online now. This is based on who has opened a page within the last 5 min. Each page load is saved to my DB, below:

[image: Database Table]

At the moment I have the following code

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id, timestamp FROM user_actions WHERE timestamp > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)");
        $onlineUsers = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

This is simply totalling the number of rows, how can I do this so it only counts a user_id once? (so in the above database snippet it should be 2 not 5)

Comment: Unless you explicitly need to return the timestamp, don't.... and then just `SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM ...`

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` api. Swap to `PDO` or `mysqli`, the `mysql` api is deprecated and removed in later versions of php (for good reasons).

Comment: `$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(user_id), timestamp FROM user_actions WHERE timestamp > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)");` try this query

Comment: Thanks @Anant :) Any idea how I can list the entries? (Also if you answer the question I can accept it)

Comment: @Anant - Could you give me an example of how I would do that? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `mysql_*` is deprecated (php 5 onward) and removed in (php 7). So a `mysqli_*` example is here:-

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','db name');//change credentials here
$online_users = array();
if($conn){

    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT DISTINCT(user_id), timestamp,page FROM user_actions WHERE timestamp > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)");

    if($query){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $online_users[] = $row;
        }
    }else{
        echo "query error:-".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}else{
    echo "db connection error:-".mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
<table>

<tr>
    <thead>
        <th>User Id</th>
        <th>timestamp></th>
        <th>Page Visited</th>
    </thead>
</tr>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($online_users as $online_user){?<
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $online_user['user_id'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $online_user['timestamp'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $online_user['page'];?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php }?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Note:-  If you want to show online user name also then you have to do `JOIN query`.

change table code accordingly.

It's a sample code. modify it accordingly.

Comment: Distinct applies to the entire resultset, not just to a single field. `SELECT DISTINCT(user_id), timestamp,page ...` will return 5 records as without distinct, since the data in `timestamp` or `page` fields are different from one another. I have no idea why the OP marked this "answer" accepted, if the expected output was 2, and not 5.

Answer (score 1):

use `DISTINCT` keyword

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(user_id), timestamp FROM user_actions WHERE timestamp > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)");
$onlineUsers = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: distinct applies across the resultset, you cannot restrict it to 1 column of the dataset only.

Answer (score 0):

You may use group by, e.g

```
SELECT user_id, timestamp FROM user_actions WHERE timestamp > date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute) group by user_id;
```

Comment: Your query is against the sql standard and would only run in MySQL under certain sql mode settings. In the recent versions of MySQL the default settings would luckily prevent this query from running.